# Twitter Bootstrap | Less Variables | How to change @linkColor without effecting buttons (btn)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am being an idiot, probably, but can someone help.

I want to change `@linkColor` to some color, but i dont want to effect any link that has the class of `btn`.

As i have already coded a lot of the site, i dont really want to add anything but css to achieve this.

I am using bootstrap with less.

thanks

Comment: i guess i should clarify, i am using have links with the class btn on them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so figured it out:

```
.btn.btn-primary {
  color: @white;
  .gradientBar(@red, @redFadeTo);
}
```